# Is it possible to design an automaton that accepts irrational number?

Tags: math, numbers, automata, number-theory

Given a rational number, would it be possible to know whether the root or some other power of the number is an irrational number? Can an automaton be designed for such a purpose?

Comment: Does "automaton" mean anything different from "program" in this context?

Comment: Program might be at a higher level and difficult to design, but an automaton would give me a basic idea. What I want to know is whether it is possible to check if the number we input is irrational. For example, if one inputs a symbol like "pi", then it should be able to detect the irrationality property.

Comment: I'm confused. Are we talking about [Finite state automatons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)? Because they're a lot less powerful than real-life computers and making them perform anything beyond trivial tasks is usually _more_ difficult than writing a program to do the same thing. And even if you prove that a task can't be performed with a FSM, that doesn't mean it can't be performed by something Turing-complete, like your PC. Are you sure you mean "automaton"? Are you maybe thinking of "algorithm"?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't being specific. I am not thinking about a Finite state automaton particularly. I want it to be more generalized. An algorithm would certainly help too. Any particular way for the computer to know if the number is an irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An irrational number is an infinite string, and if you want an automaton that can read it, it will need to continue reading infinitely.

You cannot build a decider (a machine that always halts with output true or false), but you can build an acceptor (a machine that halts with false, but continues forever for true), which is what I believe you're asking.

Consider a machine that accepts the irrational number of the form

```
0.10110111011110111110...
```

Where the lengths of runs of `1`s is always growing between `0`s. It's relatively easy to define a Turing machine that can accept this number.

(For the implementation for such a machine, I'd suggest [The Annotated Turing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470229055), which also has an implementation for a machine that accepts √2.)

Comment: I don't really think this answers the question. The input is a *rational* number x and a power y. The output is true if x**y is irrational, false otherwise. As an example, for the input of (2, 1/2) the output is true. For the input of (2,2) the output is false.

Comment: Exactly! The power of the number, which will be another rational number, can be taken as input.
I did also think that the machine might continue running forever for an irrational number. However, can the machine know that it is going to continue forever? If it knows, that might solve the problem.

Comment: No no that might not solve it. Because a number like (10 / 3) would continue forever too.

Comment: @Sitansu: "Can the machine know that it is going to continue forever?" that is called the Halting Problem, and the answer in general is no.